# PL\SQL. Цикл Loop при работе с курсором

Tags: oracle, plsql

Почему я получаю задвоеную запись в результате работы цикла LOOP ?
Мой код:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
 CURSOR get_row_from_offices IS
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM OFFICES;
  v_res get_row_from_offices%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- create loop and fetching row to v_res
  OPEN get_row_from_offices;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN get_row_from_offices%NOTFOUND;
    FETCH get_row_from_offices INTO v_res;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_res.OFFICE||' 
    '||v_res.CITY||' '||v_res.REGION||'
    '||TO_CHAR(v_res.MGR)||' 
    '||TO_CHAR(v_res.TARGET)||' 
    '||TO_CHAR(v_res.SALES));
  END LOOP;
CLOSE get_row_from_offices;
END;
```

Результат:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

1 
Kiew Ukraine
12 
2000 
5000
2 
Gdansk Poland
20 
10000 
50000
3 
Gdynya Poland
50 
20000 
5000
4 
Poznan Poland
87 
2500 
5000
5 
Frankfurt-am-Main Germany
100 
1000 
4321
6 
Hamburg Germany
90 
3000 
5000
7 
Koln Germany
100 
2800 
5300
8 
Mumbai India
120 
3000 
9000
9 
Lima Peru
150 
2900 
7000
9 
Lima Peru
150 
2900 
7000
```

Почему запись "Lima" отобразилась 2 раза?

Comment: один `Lima Peru` имеет `9` а другой нет

Comment: Когда я выполняю SELECT * FROM OFFICES; я получаю одну запись со значением "Lima"

Comment: У них разные `v_res.SALES` последные строки проверьте

Comment: @Saidolim, записи одинаковые. Ниже результат, если провписать строку DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line в один ряд:

Comment: 1 Kiew Ukraine 12 2000 5000
2 Gdansk Poland 20 10000 50000
3 Gdynya Poland 50 20000 5000
4 Poznan Poland 87 2500 5000
5 Frankfurt-am-Main Germany 100 1000 4321
6 Hamburg Germany 90 3000 5000
7 Koln Germany 100 2800 5300
8 Mumbai India 120 3000 9000
9 Lima Peru 150 2900 7000
9 Lima Peru 150 2900 7000

Comment: да оказывается там другой порядок. тут loop не правильно работает. данные нормально. Вы еще одну веш проверьте. Размер курсора выводите

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33152/discussion-between-snorri-and-saidolim).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в изначальном коде в том, что вы делаете проверку на `EXIT WHEN get_row_from_offices%NOTFOUND;` до того, как сделаете `FETCH`. Потому как признак `NOTFOUND` на курсоре может установить только FETCH при попытке чтения уже окончившихся данных. Если запись была только одна то происходит следующее: на первой итерации `FETCH` читает строку, но он еще не знает, что данные закончились и `NOTFOUND` не устанавливает, вы уходите на вторую итерацию, `EXIT` не срабатывает, `FETCH` пытается прочитать следующую запись, ее нет, он устанавливает `NOTFOUND`, но в переменной курсора данные предыдущей записи остаются. Вы их печатаете. Правильно использовать курсоры так:

```
LOOP
 FETCH get_row_from_offices INTO v_res;
 EXIT WHEN get_row_from_offices%NOTFOUND;
 ...
```

В вашем случае использование явных курсоров излишне, предлагаю использовать более простой синтаксис:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
 FOR v_res IN(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM OFFICES) LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_res.OFFICE||' 
     '||v_res.CITY||' '||v_res.REGION||'
     '||TO_CHAR(v_res.MGR)||' 
     '||TO_CHAR(v_res.TARGET)||' 
     '||TO_CHAR(v_res.SALES));
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike, за пример, но использовать курсор было условием задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CURSOR get_row_from_offices IS
SELECT * FROM OFFICES;
v_res get_row_from_offices%ROWTYPE;
OPEN get_row_from_offices;
LOOP
EXIT WHEN get_row_from_offices%NOTFOUND;
FETCH get_row_from_offices INTO v_res;
DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_res.OFFICE||'
'||v_res.CITY||' '||v_res.REGION||'
'||TO_CHAR(v_res.MGR)||'     
'||TO_CHAR(v_res.TARGET)||'
'||TO_CHAR(v_res.SALES));
END LOOP;
CLOSE get_row_from_offices;
END;
```

Обьявил неявный курсор и вывод стал правильным.